# I have error in `define on the Verilog with for

Tags: verilog, hdl

```
...
'define ZERO_INIT2D(VECT,SD_WIDTH) for(integer i=0;i<(SD_WIDTH);i=i+1) (VECT)[i]=0;
...`

...
reg [31:0] rrr [7:0];
...
always @(negedge clk)
begin
        ZERO_INIT2D(rrr,8)
        //for(integer i=0;i<8;i=i+1) rrr[i]=0;// if using it. All works fine
        Buffer_reg = 111;
        Start_addr = 0;
        Counter=0;
...
```

I want to use exactly define!
My define has nothing to do with the register "Buffer_reg". Why am I getting the following error?

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "MEMORY_m.v" Line 170: Syntax error near "Buffer_reg".
ERROR:ProjectMgmt - 1 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made such changes and everything was synthesized normally: ...

`...
'define ZERO_INIT2D(VECT,SD_WIDTH) for(integer i=0;i<SD_WIDTH;i=i+1) VECT[i]=0;
...`

I do not know why but

> (VECT) -> VECT
>
> (SD_WIDTH) -> SD_WIDTH

and it helped, but this also violates the syntax of defines, well, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your code. Here is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with them corrected:

```
module M;

//|                                                                      |  
//V                                                                      V 
  `define ZERO_INIT2D(VECT,SD_WIDTH) for(integer i=0;i<(SD_WIDTH);i=i+1) VECT[i]=0;

  reg [31:0] rrr [7:0];

  always @*
    begin
//    |
//    V   
      `ZERO_INIT2D(rrr,8)
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3Db3

---

When asking a question, it is better to prepare an MCVE yourself rather than expecting those helping you to do it. Not only does it save others some work, it will help explain your problem more clearly and you may well spot the answer yourself whilst preparing it.